# Parse's REST API and PHP Curl requests - how to

Tags: php, parsing, rest, curl

I am using the excellent [Parse](https://parse.com/) as a data store, but need to access it through PHP (as a perhaps irrelevant bit of detail - I am having to access it through PHP in order for Facebook scrapers to recognise dynaically generated  tags on my page).

Parse have a Rest API, and basic instructions on how to use them. For example, to retrieve an object:

> curl -X GET \
>   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: [My application ID]" \
>   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: [My Parse Rest API key]" \
>    https://api.parse.com/1/classes/moods/

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to integrate this with PHP Curl examples I've seen online. I gather:

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,

..might be involved. As might:

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

but I could be way off. I am really sorry to not be able to figure this out myself - but I think this is still a valid question as it is very confusing to those who haven't used Curl/PHP before. Basically - I'm looking for information as basic as where to put the quoted example from the Parse docs...

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Hey all, here is the solution as I configured it. Thanks to debianek for getting me going in the right direction.

```
if ($_GET['id']) {
$imageId = $_GET['id']; 
MyApplicationId = '[ID]';
$MyParseRestAPIKey = '[API Key]';
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/images/'.$imageId;

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $MyApplicationId,
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $MyParseRestAPIKey
);

    $handle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

$array = json_decode($data);

$title =  $array->title;
```

..and so on. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, you said you figured how to use it. Could you post here the solution

Comment: In the edit. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: The solution should be in a separate answer, *not* in the question itself.  Remove it from here and put it into a new answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it into headers

```
$headers = array(
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: $MyApplicationId",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: $MyParseRestAPIkey"
);

$handle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. With a bit of extra tweaking I got this working. I will edit my original post to reflect this when I have a complete solution. Which leads to my next sub-question.

I have, I believe, a JSON object in my PHP. The HTTP_HEADER text output confirms it was fetched correctly.

$data = curl_exec($handle);
$array = json_decode($data, true);

When I try and echo out $data in my html body, however, I get "error: unauthorised" and echo-ing out $array echoes out the word "array." Trying $array['objectId'] or $array[0].objectId returns a blank. Any further help massively appreciated..

Answer (score 4):

```
 <?php  
 $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore';  
 $appId = 'YOUR_APP_ID';  
 $restKey = 'YOUR_REST_KEY';  
 $headers = array(  
   "Content-Type: application/json",  
   "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,  
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey  
 );  
 $objectData = '{"name":"Adarsh", "age":"26"}';  
 $rest = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$objectData);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
 $response = curl_exec($rest);  
 echo $response;  
 print_r($response);  
 curl_close($rest);  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function   for all object insert ,the object that should be created as associative array with correct index

```
 function insertObject($classname,$object){
 $ appId="xxxxx";
   $restKey="xxxx" 
    $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/'.$classname;
    $rest = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, FALSE);//use cache if available
        curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //10 sec timeout
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_PORT,443);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($object));
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
                "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey,
                "Content-Type: application/json"));

        curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//to avoid certificate error
        $response = curl_exec($rest);
        echo $response ;

}
```