# Parse.com REST API with cURL and C++

Tags: c++, json, rest, curl, parse-platform

I have a raspberry pi that is running a c++ program. It now needs to talk to the Parse.com cloud so it seems the REST API is the best choice. I've been programming for a year and have truly hit a wall here.

EDIT: I've been able to get the code below to run. It successfully posts "south" in a new row under the "direction" column. I had to link my compiler to -lcurl.

My remaining question is how can I in this syntax add conditions to the query? For me the limiting query is 
`WHERE hardwareType = 2`.

I can also GET all the results of my parse table if I comment out the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS line inside curl_easy_init. How can I limit this request with the same query quoted above?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;

    headerlist = curl_slist_append( headerlist, "X-Parse-Application-Id: aaaaaaaaaaa");
    headerlist = curl_slist_append( headerlist, "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
    headerlist = curl_slist_append( headerlist, "Content-Type: application/json");
    //headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "-d '{"direction":"south"}'");

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/testing");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"direction\" : \"south\"}");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK){
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This seems to be a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738065/parses-rest-api-and-php-curl-requests-how-to), using the full API rather than just `curl_easy`. PS: When you have a problem, please report the exact error message and you will get more replies.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: My apologies Ken Y-N & s_b, I updated my post to reflect it was not an error message, but a blank post to Parse. 

Ken Y-N, thank you for the link - it did help with some understanding, but I am new to programming and have not had the change to study PHP yet .